# How to use a method with sender and e parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have this code where I want to call the `set_background` void in the `resize_Handler` void. How would I do that? I tried `set_background(null, PaintEventArgs());` inside the `resize_Handler`, but it says `non-invocable member cannot be used like a method`.

My code:

```
private void set_background(Object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;

    Rectangle gradient_rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);

    Brush b = new LinearGradientBrush(gradient_rectangle, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255), Color.FromArgb(255, 102, 54), 0f);
 
    graphics.FillRectangle(b, gradient_rectangle);
}

private void resize_Handler(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    // where I want to call set_background()
}
```

Comment: `PaintEventArgs` is a type - so `PaintEventArgs()` isn't valid. But `new PaintEventArgs()` would be.

Comment: Although I have to ask what you'd expect `e.Graphics` to be in that case... fundamentally these methods are expected to be used as event handlers rather than called directly.

Comment: @JonSkeet, but I want it to be called when the window resizes. Can you provide some information about that. I tried doing ```set_background(null, new PaintEventArgs(null, new Rectangle()));```, but it also didn't work either. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually I think the solution is `this.Invalidate()` or `this.Update()` or `this.Refresh()` (combination of both). Otherwise the problem will be that you don't know which graphics object to use. You have probably hooked that up to the [Paint event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) anyway, just with a strange name.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to call an event handler directly, refactor the code in the event handler to its own method, and call the new method instead.

```
private void SetBackground(Graphics graphics)
{        
    Rectangle gradient_rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);

    Brush b = new LinearGradientBrush(gradient_rectangle, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255), Color.FromArgb(255, 102, 54), 0f);
 
    graphics.FillRectangle(b, gradient_rectangle);
}

private void set_background(Object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
   SetBackground(e.Graphics);
}

private void resize_Handler(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
   Graphics graphics = new Graphics(); // or whatever applies here.
   SetBackground(graphics);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I couldn't even come up with this. But I have an error that goes as follows: ```'Graphics' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments```.

Comment: Right, that's why I put that comment there.  You have to work out what your graphics object needs to contain before you pass it to your new `SetBackground` method.

Comment: Perhaps it's somewhere in your `Object sender` or `EventArgs` from your `resize_Handler`?

Comment: @SabawoonEnayat: now I'd like to know how you solved the graphics problem, please

Comment: Thanks man. My problem was something else. I really appreciate your hard work.

Comment: I just had to change, ```Graphics graphics = new Graphics(); // or whatever applies here.
   SetBackground(graphics);```, in ```resize_Handler``` to ```this.Invalidate();```